# How to resolve chrome frameset target attribute issue

Tags: google-chrome, target, frameset

I'm using html frameset in one of my page. where i've divided that frameset to 3 frames. Like..

1. TitleFrame
2. LeftColFrame
3. RightColFrame

In my 'LeftColFrame' frame i've couple of links which has target attribute value as 'RightColFrame '. Every things are going fine except when i click any links from 'LeftColFrame ' it's opening the content in a new browser tab rather than opening in 'RightColFrame'.

Don't know what's going wrong. After googling , i got to know Chrome has some issue with Frameset. But, didn't got real solution to avoid this thing.

So, if any body have any idea about this plz share with me.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried using the `target` attribute on your links and giving your iframes corresponding `id`s? http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/qt/target-links-iframes-and-frames.htm

Comment: @apsillers Ya, I've done like that. But, still the link is opening in a new browser tab.

Comment: Glad you solved it -- go ahead and post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holly Shit!!! 
Guys, after 4hr of extensive debugging now i got the cause for which all these crap was happening. The thing is... in one of my javascript file i've used a variable by name as 'name'. Like this..

```
var name = false;
```

And, this 'name' was creating problem in webkit page rendering engine which used by both Google Chrome & Safari. After, googling a bit i got to know that 'name' is a reserve keyword in JavaScript. But,even if this.. IE & Mozilla have no issue with it. But, webkit has some issue.